# Passing anonymous users from one view to another in Django 3.0.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a fully anonymous survey, where the survey participant enters a landing site (index.html), clicks a link and is directed to a survey view. On this survey (pre_test.html) page, I want to assign a new Participant object with a primary key and link that to the Survey model via a foreign key. Because this Survey isn't the main part of my study, I want to send that Participant object to a new view, where the Participant primary key is again used as a foreign key to link to another model (call it Task).

What I've tried so far in the views.py is:

```
def pre_test(request):        
    if request.method == "POST":
        participant = Participants()
        participant.save()  
        participant_pk = participant.pk
        form = PreTestQuestionnaireForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            post_primary = PreTestQuestionnaire(pk=post.pk)  
            post_primary.Analyst_id = Participants(pk=participant_pk)
            post_primary.save()  
            request.session['user'] = participant_pk
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:picture_test'))  
    else:
        form = PreTestQuestionnaireForm()
    return render(request, 'study/pre_test.html', {'form': form})

def picture_test(request):
    obj = Participants(Unique_ID=request.session.get('user')) # Unique_ID is the pk I've set for Participants
```

but when calling `print(obj)` all I get is Participants object (None). What am I missing in using the session? Should I not be using sessions in this way at all, or should I create actual users in another table without giving them passwords and other data? Keeping the users anonymous is essential and I want to avoid cookies as much as possible, although I can write code to remove cookies after each session.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the culprit.

I had set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True` in the `settings.py` file, which blocks cookies from working well in localhost development and thus using `request.session.get()` doesn't return anything.